# Fluent NHibernate Complex Composite Key Mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm afraid to even ask this question really, as I find the whole thing pretty disgusting myself. But, what are you going to do with a legacy database.

I have the following three tables

```
Generator    Alarm          AlarmDescription
---------    -----          ----------------
             Id             Id
Id        <- GensetId       DescriptionText
             EventTypeId -> AlarmCode
PanelId   ----------------> PanelId
```

If it's not clear from the above rendering, I have an Alarm, which has both a Genset and an AlarmDescription. The Genset is directly mappable via the GensetId property. The AlarmDescription should also be easily mappable off the Id property right? But it wasn't designed that way, and instead is mapped off a composite of `(AlarmCode, PanelId)` (note, they don't even share the same field name, found this out after struggling to find any relation until inspecting the data).

So, how would you map this using Fluent NHibernate? I've tried a couple variations, but have failed. Something like the following would be ... ideal, but I don't think anything like this is necessarily directly available.

```
 References(x => x.AlarmDescription)
      .Column("AlarmCode", m => m.EventTypeId)
      .Column("PanelId", m => m.Genset.PanelId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried formulas? (Sorry, I am not using fluent.)

```
<many-to-one name="AlarmDescription">
  <column name="EventTypeId" />
  <formula>(select g.PanelId from Generator g where g.Id = GensetId)</formula>
</many-to-one>
```

This requires declaring `AlarmDescription` primary key as being the [composite id](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid) (`AlarmCode`, `PanelId`).

If you need to preserve `AlarmDescription` id, then add in it a [natural-id](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-naturalid) as a [component](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-component):

```
<class name="AlarmDescription">
  <id name="Id">
    <generator .../>
  </id>
  <natural-id>
    <component name="AlarmDescriptionNaturalId">
      <property name="AlarmCode" />
      <property name="PanelId" />
    </component>
  </natural-id>
  ...
```

And reference it as the key for your relation in `Alarm` thanks to [`property-ref`](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone):

```
<many-to-one name="AlarmDescription" property-ref="AlarmDescriptionNaturalId">
  <column name="EventTypeId" />
  <formula>(select g.PanelId from Generator g where g.Id = GensetId)</formula>
</many-to-one>
```

Comment: Formulas are the conclusion I've come to as well, I was just hoping there was a nicer / more magical way to do it.

Comment: At first I was not even thinking we may have a way to map that. I would not expect to have any other solution than using formula (or altering the db) for such a case.